# Problems getting hot link php with htaccess to work

Tags: .htaccess, hotlinking

I have a php script that watermarks hotlinked images that isn't working, I always get the linked image. I think the problem is in the htaccess file and I can't figure out why it doesn't work.  When I go to this url the php file shows the watermarked image http://www.example.com/watermark.php?path=http://www.example.com/photos/image.jpg

This is the code I have.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .*jpg$|.*gif$|.*png$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !example\.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !google\. [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !search\?q=cache [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) watermark.php?path=$1
#or RewriteRule (.*) /watermark.php?path=$1
```

The reason I think it is the htaccess and not the php file is that when I have these two lines in the php file it still does not work.

```
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
readfile('images/sun.jpg');
```

Comment: What other directives do you have in the `.htaccess` file? How are you testing this? What is the value of `Referer` header in your tests?

Comment: I have other things in the htaccess file, but even when I remove everything else I get the same results. I am testing by inserting one of my images in another website, completely different sever.  I'm not sure how to determine the value.

Comment: You need to check the HTTP request (and response) headers that are being sent to your server. Specifically, the `Referer` header. AND check the `Server` response header. You can do this in the browser dev tools as you click the link. Please add this information to your question. However, your directives would rewrite the request to `/watermark.php?path=photos/image.jpg`, not `/watermark.php?path=http://www.example.com/photos/image.jpg` as you stated in your example.